# PowerShell New Pipline variable with String/ArrayValue in "{}"

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables

I need a solution to create an array in a certain format.

Background I export a SharePoint list and get my fields from an XML file.

The command (via PnP) to export is as follows:

```
$AllSPListItems = Get-PnPListItem $SharePointListName

$ItemsSelection = @{ L = "ID"; E = { $_["ID"] } },@{ L = "SP_SiteURL"; E = { $_["SP_SiteURL"] } }

$AllSPListItems | Select $ItemsSelection | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\XYZ.csv"
```

That works, but here's what I want:

```
$ItemsSelection = @{ L = "$FieldDisplayName[0]"; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[0]] } },@{ L = "$FieldDisplayName[1]"; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[1]] } } }
```

I get the `$FieldDisplayName` and `$FieldURLName` variables from my XML.

Unfortunately I only get the following output:

```
@{ L = "ID"; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[0]] } },@{ L = "SP_SiteURL"; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[1]] } } }

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                     
E                              $FieldURLName[0]                                                                                                                 
L                              ID
E                              $FieldURLName[1]                                                                                                                 
L                              SP_SiteURL
```

So how can I get the value of "E", not the text?
The variables does not resolves.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't put `"` around `$FieldDisplayName[0]`

Answer (score 0):

> So how can I get the value of "E", not the text?

You get the text of the `E` scriptblock because *it hasn't executed yet* - that only happens once you use it with `Select-Object`.

To get the correct label names, remove the `"` quotes around the label expression:

```
$ItemsSelection = @{ L = $FieldDisplayName[0]; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[0]] } },@{ L = $FieldDisplayName[1]; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[1]] } } }
$AllSPListItems | Select $ItemsSelection | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\XYZ.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks, but the Value of the $FieldDisplayName is not the problem, that works fine. The Problem is "E". Is there no way in "Select-Object" with use a String/Array?

Comment: If the value of `$FieldURLName[0]` is the name of a property you want to reference you can do `@{L='NewName';E=$FieldURLName[0]}` directly

Comment: I tried. It works for the Field "ID" but for other Fields doesn`t work it, only with pipline $_ ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have a solution, is unattractive but apparently there is no other possibility.
I use the switch Case:

switch ($FieldDisplayName.Length){

```
1 {$items | Select @{ L = $FieldDisplayName[0]; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[0]] } } | Export-Csv -Path "C:\install\ExportV1.csv"} 
2 {$items | Select @{ L = $FieldDisplayName[0]; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[0]] } },@{ L = $FieldDisplayName[1]; E = { $_[$FieldURLName[1]] } } | Export-Csv -Path "C:\install\ExportV1.csv"}
```

}